# Unexpected behavior of search functionality eclipse cdt (kepler)

Tags: eclipse

I was using **Eclipse CDT 3.8** *(Indigo, I think)* with a generated project from cmake, and everything went well to me. But recently I change to **Eclipse CDT Kepler** *(same project, generated again to match the new Eclipse version, 4.3 )* and now the search functionality isn't working properly, some things I was capable to  find in the older version, I cant find them now.

I did my homework,  and I looked for some incompatibility issues. Without results.

Some one knows which can be the problem.

Comment: what **exactly** was the new eclipse unable to find that the older on did?

Comment: Some functions names. I tried to see if it was a problem of indexing, but, it is not.

Comment: Which search function are you using? I had a similar problem when using Java search. Using File search did the trick for me (even though all the relevant files were, in fact, Java).

Comment: Yes, that actually works for other kinds of projects, on the other hand,  remember I'm working in a project generated from cmake. So i'm afraid that can cause some issues.

However I'm going to test your sugestion.

Comment: Venite: as I suspected "search files", did not worked. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, the version of cdt that comes by default with Eclipse cdt Kepler, is non compatible with cmake's generator. I simply don't used any variable for the eclipse version when generating the project, and "cmake" set it to 3.6 (Helios) by default. And that way, search functions start to work. I hope, not have broken nothing more :-).